# Filtering out non-matching characters when using a regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a string which has to be matching @"^[\w*$][\w\s-$]*((\d{1,})){0,1}$".

If it doesn't match this regular expression, I want the characters that do not match to be deleted from the string. How can I set this up?

Comment: when is \d supposed to match ? digits are already included in \w.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^[^[\w*\$][\w\s-\$]*((\d{1,})){0,1}]$", "")
```

Comment: This will replace all characters from the regex above, i want the characters that are NOT in this regex to be replaced. This has to be reverted if possible.

Comment: @Younes = ^ char is stand for not

Comment: ^ char indicates line's beginning

Comment: Thanks i didn't see that u had put a ^inside the bracket :)

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., *why* does it work? *How* does it work? What is the gist? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3635269/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like (but I am not sure of the actual question). Maybe you want to remove the whole regex if it does not match; that's not what the code below does:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^[^\w*\$]([\w*\$])[^\w*\$\s-]*([\w\s-\$]*).*$", "$1$2")
```

The idea is to interleave each wanted character blocks with list of forbidden characters and keep only those that you want. The end of your regex was a bit strange, so I simplified it.

Comment: As you see I'm not the best with regular expressions. I am planning to go and dive into this topic soon. Thanks for your help.